# ExecutorService not execute after onPause()

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm currently working on an android game using libgdx. When game close, I need to save data to the server via network in onPause() method. The executorService then submit a task to send data. But afterward, this task is never executed.
Is anyone experienced with this situation, please help me understand, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running into a pure Android problem (nothing to do with Libgdx).  The standard Java `ExecutorService` creates a background thread, so your `onPause` method will return immediately.  At this point the system believes your application is done pausing, and may be terminated at any time.  See:

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html
- [How does Android handle background threads when leaving an Activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898447/how-does-android-handle-background-threads-when-leaving-an-activity)

The right way to save data over the network is to use an (Android) "Service" in your application so that the system knows you have on-going background work.  See [How to save state in Android onPause using android HttpRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14800054/how-to-save-state-in-android-onpause-using-androidhttprequest)